# By grouping terms as appropriate show that $\frac{7}{12} \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \leq \frac{47}{60}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm not totally sure how to do this problem...

By grouping terms as appropriate show that $\frac{7}{12} \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \leq \frac{47}{60}$

I've got that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{4} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = \frac{7}{12}$

and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{5} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = \frac{47}{60} $

And that, by the alternating series test, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ converges. However, I'm not sure what it converges to and if that will uphold my inequality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The thing to show is that the even terms always increase but never increase as much as the previous odd term and the odd terms always decrease but never as much as the previous even term.  (i.e $\sum^{2n} < \sum^{2n+2} < \sum^{2n+1}<\sum^{2n-1}$)

Answer (score 4):

Let $$S=\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}.$$
Since $S$ is a conditionally convergent series: alternating and $|t_{k+1}|<|t_k|$, we can write
$$1-1/2+1/3-1/4 < S < 1-1/2+1/3-1/4+1/5$$

EDIT:

For convergence of a series you may see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence

Comment: How do we get that we can just say that $|t_{k+1}| \lt |t_k|$?

Comment: Convergence  of a series is is an essential topic to understand first see my edit,

Comment: @Thales There is a theorem about **convergent alternating series partial sums** that you should have been taught:  Let $L$ be the limit of the series $a_1 - a_2 + a_3 - a_4 \cdots ~: ~a_i > 0,~$ and let $k$ be any positive integer.  Then $$\sum_{i=1}^{2k} -1^{n+1} a_i < L < \sum_{i=1}^{2k+1} -1^{n+1} a_i.$$

Comment: @user2661923 Yep, definitely wasn't shown this. Thank you!

Comment: @ZAhmed Thank you for your help! I was able to get it.

Comment: @Thales Re my previous comment, it was **informal**.  For the exact premises for the theorem, which this particular problem happens to satisfy, you should track down the actual theorem.

Answer (score 2):

I will do something better. Consider that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{m+1}=\sum_{m\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1}(-x)^m\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x}$$
and that $x(1-x)\leq \frac{1}{4}$ over $(0,1)$. In particular the integral
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x}\,dx $$
is positive and bounded by $\frac{1}{4^4}=\frac{1}{2^8}$. Also, by partial fraction decomposition, such integral equals
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^7-5x^6+11x^5-15x^4+16x^3-16x^2+16x-16\right)\,dx + 16\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x} $$
hence
$$ 0 \leq -\frac{621}{56}+16\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \leq \frac{1}{2^8} $$
and
$$\boxed{ \color{blue}{\frac{621}{896}} \leq \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \leq \color{blue}{\frac{621}{896}+\frac{1}{2^{12}}}}\tag{A} $$
By simplifying the continued fraction of the LHS we also get the weaker but simpler bound
$$\boxed{ \color{blue}{\frac{70}{101}} \leq \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \leq \color{blue}{\frac{61}{88}}}\tag{B} $$